# iPhone Keyboard Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard

I'm working with a new app that use the class **JLBPartialModal** of **Jonathan Badeen**, this class attempts to mimic the interface in National Geographic's Park Guides.

My problem is this, when I try to show the keyboard at the second view, the first time this happens everything looks fine, the problem comes the second time, the keyboard is smaller but still works in its original size.

**First Time** https://i.stack.imgur.com/kByhh.png

**Second Time** https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNhbL.png

I do not know if there is any way to force the second view has the **becomeFirstResponder**.

Hopefully have any suggestions to solve my problem.

#### First View

View is called using a **IBAction**

```
-(IBAction)accion:(id)sender{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    composeViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"composeView"];

    JLBPartialModal *partialModal = [JLBPartialModal sharedInstance];
    partialModal.delegate = vc;

    [partialModal presentViewController:vc dismissal:^{

    }];
}
```

#### Second view

The class have 3 delegates, one of the didPresentPartialModalView, I'm using this delegate for show the keyboard after the view and animation ends:

```
#pragma mark - Partial modal delegate

- (void)didPresentPartialModalView:(JLBPartialModal *)partialModal
{
     self.texto.editable = YES;
     [self.texto becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then, when the user touch Close button the UITextView have **resignFirstResponder** and with the **NSNotificationCenter** I know that the keyboard is hidden:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    self.texto.editable = NO;
    [self.texto resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)KeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [[JLBPartialModal sharedInstance] dismissViewController];
}

- (BOOL)shouldDismissPartialModalView:(JLBPartialModal *)partialModal
{
   return YES;
}
```

Thank you.

### Edit

**Finally!**

I've solved my problem adding **removedOnCompletion** into **JLBPartialModal.m**

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)pullBackAnimation
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)pushForwardAnimation
```

Like this:

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)pullBackAnimation
{
    CATransform3D startTransform = [self perspectiveTransform];
    CATransform3D endTransform = CATransform3DConcat([self windowScaledTransform], startTransform);
    CATransform3D middleTransform = CATransform3DConcat([self windowRotationTransform], startTransform);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [self windowAnimation];
    anim.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:startTransform], [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:middleTransform], [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform]];

    anim.removedOnCompletion = YES; // Line added

    return anim;
}

- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)pushForwardAnimation
{
    CATransform3D endTransform = [self perspectiveTransform];
    CATransform3D startTransform = CATransform3DConcat([self windowScaledTransform], endTransform);
    CATransform3D middleTransform = CATransform3DConcat([self windowRotationTransform], startTransform);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [self windowAnimation];
    anim.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:startTransform], [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:middleTransform], [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform]];

     anim.removedOnCompletion = YES; // Line added

    return anim;
}
```

With this I make sure that the animations are removed :D

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code of the second view

Comment: See my answer, I've updated it to be specific to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a bit with the JLBPartialModal control.  It looks like the author adds an animation with a scale in `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent dismissal:(void (^)(void))block`,

```
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (window != self.window) {
            [window.layer addAnimation:[self pullBackAnimation] forKey:@"pullBackAnimation"];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:JLB_PARTIAL_MODAL_ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
                window.center = CGPointMake(window.center.x, window.center.y - JLB_PARTIAL_MODAL_WINDOW_VERTICAL_OFFSET);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (!hasCalledDelegate) {
                    [self.delegate didPresentPartialModalView:self];
                    hasCalledDelegate = YES;
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

then removes this animation in `- (void)dismissViewController`.

```
        for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
            [window.layer removeAllAnimations];
        }
```

He assumes that the array of `windows` in the first method is the same set of windows in the dismissal method, which I would perhaps question.  It would appear that your keyboard is in a window that has this scale attribute set on it, but has not been removed.

Therefore, I recommend that when you either fix the problem with the component, or as an interim fix, you  perform this second loop (the removeAllAnimations one) in response to the keyboard being displayed.

I'm not 100% confident this is the answer without seeing your code.  You may be doing something elsewhere that is affecting the state of the window system.

EDIT:  Now that you have posted code, I think I can see the problem.  The notification you are signing up for is KeyboardDidHide... but you treat it as a "WillHide" notification.  By the time you call the `dismissViewController` on the JLBPartialModal sharedInstance, the keyboard is no longer in the set of windows in the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` property.  This means the animation is NOT removed from the window containing the keyboard.  What you have will probably work if you change `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

Comment: Mmmm I see... I'll do a couple of test to see if I can solve the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @OCRickard I've change the notification type UIKeyboardDidHideNotification to UIKeyboardWillHideNotification and the problem persist.  I'm looking into JLBPartialModal class to see if I can fix my problem, thank you for your help.